# Can I initialize a `thread_local` from an async function?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to initialize a `thread_local!` from an async function.

When I try to compile the code I currently have, the compiler throws an error telling me that it expected a type of `std::rc::Rc` but found an `opaque type`.

My code looks something like this

```rust
async fn async_function() -> std::rc::Rc<SomeTypeWhichImplementsStdFuture> {
   let some_type = SomeTypeWhichImplementsStdFuture::new();
   std::rc::Rc::new(match some_type.await {
      OutputOfSomeTypesFuture::Success => {
         some_type
      }
      OutputOfSomeTypesFuture::Error => {
        panic!("some error");
      }
   });
}

thread_local!(
    pub static SOME_TYPE_THREAD_LOCAL: std::rc::Rc<SomeTypeWhichImplementsStdFuture> 
    = async_function());
```

Which gives the error `error[E0308]: mismatched types`.

Is this possible? If not, how else could I go about achieving this?

Comment: I don't think you can do it. Calling `async_function` in your example actually returns `impl Future<Output=Rc<SomeType...>`, and to unwrap this future you would need to await it, which requires an asyncronous runtime, which is lacking in global context.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I could make the thread stop any computation until the async value has resolved?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what exactly you are trying to do. Consider opening a separate question with a code sample, preferably a one that can be run in the playground (play.rust-lang.org/)

Comment: Oh. Sorry; I'll try that then! Thanks very much for your assistance.